# Zend Studio 9 tabbing with new line

Tags: zend-studio

```
$arr = array(
        );
```

It looks like this when i press enter for a new line when I'm defining an array.
It is always 2 tabs instead of 1. I didn't have this problem in Zend Studio 8. 
Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Windows

<kbd>Window</kbd> > Preferences > PHP > Code Style > Formatter > <kbd>Edit...</kbd> > **Line Wrapping**

Set **Default indentation for array initializers** to **0**.

### Mac

<kbd>Zend Studio</kbd> > Preferences > PHP > Code Style > Formatter > <kbd>Edit...</kbd> > **Line Wrapping**

Set **Default indentation for array initializers** to **0**.