# Eclipse - PHP - Seeking a "Enter key adjusts the indentation on the new line" option

Tags: php, eclipse, ide, eclipse-juno

Just got Eclipse Juno because my old version of Eclipse (Helios) was running extremely slow on large PHP files. Juno fixed that problem.

Now I have a very simple cosmetic problem: When I hit Enter, the new line starts with no indentation. In Helios, it would auto-indent to match the current indentation level (or smartly indent +1).

There's no option for this in the preferences, even though it exists for every other language in the IDE.

Any solution?

Comment: Same thing happens in updated version of Zend Studio 9.  (9.0.4 I think).  It appears ZS inherited that issue from Eclipse.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036550/zend-studio-9-tabbing-with-new-line

Comment: Link above solves a bit of a different problem than the one I've described above. More of an emphasis on being several tabs in, and having a return start at a tab index of 0.

Comment: Yeah then I don't know.  I think it's a bug. But it's really annoying!

Comment: This was closed as off-topic? FAQ reads "software tools commonly used by programmers".

Comment: More info on the bug:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=428199